# VB Script help in writing event logs to excel

Tags: vbscript

I have the below script to fetch the event logs from system and write to an excel. It is running fine on 'Windows 7', but on 'Windows Server 2003', it is taking 7-8 minutes to write the systems logs, and it writes the Application logs within seconds. However there are very few number of errors in the system logs.

Another problem is I am using MyDate = DateAdd("h", -8, Now()) in the script but it fetches logs for more than 12 hours ago. This time calculation is not functioning correctly.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objWMI, objItem, objItem1, objItem2 ' Objects
Dim strComputer, strFileName, strFileOpen, strFolder, strPath, oExcel, oWB, oSheet, oSheet1, oSheet2  
Dim intEvent, intNumberID, intRecordNum, colLoggedEvents, colLoggedEvents2, colLoggedEvents3, MyDate, dtm, row,      row1, row2, Query, ServerTime
MyDate = DateAdd("h", -8, Now())

'---------------------------------------------------------

On Error Resume Next

Set oExcel=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible=true
Set oWB=oExcel.Workbooks.Open ("D:\EventLogs2.xls")
Set oSheet=oWB.Worksheets.Add ( , oWB.WorkSheets(oWB.WorkSheets.Count))
Set oSheet1=oWB.Worksheets.Add ( , oWB.WorkSheets(oWB.WorkSheets.Count))
Set oSheet2=oWB.Worksheets.Add ( , oWB.WorkSheets(oWB.WorkSheets.Count))
oSheet.Name="Application"
oSheet1.Name="Security"
oSheet2.Name="System"

strComputer = "." 
ServerTime = Now              

intRecordNum = 0
row = 0
row1 = 0
row2 = 0

' ----------------------------------------------------------
' WMI Core Section 
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colLoggedEvents = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
       ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile = 'Application' and " _ 
        & "EventType = '1' and TimeWritten > '" & MyDate & "'")
Set colLoggedEvents2 = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
       ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile = 'Security' and " _         
        & "EventType = '1' and TimeWritten > '" & MyDate & "'")
Set colLoggedEvents3 = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
       ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile = 'System' and " _ 
        & "EventType = '1' and TimeWritten > '" & MyDate & "'")

' ----------------------------------------------------------
' Next section loops through ID properties

For Each objItem in colLoggedEvents                                    
If objItem.EventType=1 then                                                        
row = row+1
osheet.Cells(row,1).Value = ("Logfile: " & objItem.Logfile _ 
& " source " & objItem.SourceName) 
osheet.Cells(row,2).Value = ("Message: " & objItem.Message)
osheet.Cells(row,3).Value = ("TimeGenerated: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem.TimeGenerated))
osheet.Cells(row,4).Value = ServerTime

End If
Next


For Each objItem1 in colLoggedEvents2
If objItem1.EventType=1 then
row1 = row1+1
osheet1.Cells(row1,1).Value = ("Logfile: " & objItem1.Logfile _ 
& " source " & objItem1.SourceName) 
osheet1.Cells(row1,2).Value = ("Message: " & objItem1.Message)
osheet1.Cells(row1,3).Value = ("TimeGenerated: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem1.TimeGenerated))
osheet1.Cells(row1,4).Value = ServerTime

End If
Next                                                               


For Each objItem2 in colLoggedEvents3        
If objItem2.EventType=1 then
row2 = row2+1
osheet2.Cells(row2,1).Value = ("Logfile: " & objItem2.Logfile _ 
& " source " & objItem2.SourceName) 
osheet2.Cells(row2,2).Value = ("Message: " & objItem2.Message)
osheet2.Cells(row2,3).Value = ("TimeGenerated: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem2.TimeGenerated))
osheet2.Cells(row2,4).Value = ServerTime

intRecordNum = intRecordNum +1
End If
Next

Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmDate) 
 WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _ 
 Mid(dtmDate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmDate, 4) _ 
 & " " & Mid (dtmDate, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmDate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmDate,13, 2)) 
End Function

oWB.save
oWB.Application.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: 7-8 what? Minutes? Hours? Gallons? Have you determined which step in your script is consuming too much time (e.g. by logging timestamps before/after each step)?

Comment: So sorry, forgot to mention, it is 7-8 minutes.

Comment: Again, have you determined which step in your script is consuming too much time?

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, actually I am going on a holiday, I will join back my office on 10th March, then I will check it and definitely let you know. Thank you so much for following up on this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just write to a CSV file?

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objWMI, objItem, objItem1, objItem2 ' Objects
Dim strComputer, strFileName, strFileOpen, strFolder, strPath, oExcel, oWB, oSheet, oSheet1, oSheet2  
Dim intEvent, intNumberID, intRecordNum, colLoggedEvents, colLoggedEvents2, colLoggedEvents3, MyDate, dtm, row,      row1, row2, Query, ServerTime
MyDate = DateAdd("h", -8, Now())

'---------------------------------------------------------

On Error Resume Next

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("D:\EventLogs2.csv", True)

strComputer = "." 
ServerTime = Now              

intRecordNum = 0
row = 0
row1 = 0
row2 = 0

' ----------------------------------------------------------
' WMI Core Section 
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Security)}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colLoggedEvents = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
       ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile = 'Application' and " _ 
        & "EventType = '1' and TimeWritten > '" & MyDate & "'")
Set colLoggedEvents2 = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
       ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile = 'Security' and " _         
        & "EventType = '1' and TimeWritten > '" & MyDate & "'")
Set colLoggedEvents3 = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
       ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile = 'System' and " _ 
        & "EventType = '1' and TimeWritten > '" & MyDate & "'")

' ----------------------------------------------------------
' Next section loops through ID properties

For Each objItem in colLoggedEvents                                    
If objItem.EventType=1 then                                                        
    objFile.WriteLine("Logfile: " & objItem.Logfile & "," & " source " & objItem.SourceName & "," & _
        "Message: " & objItem.Message & "," & _
        "TimeGenerated: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem.TimeGenerated) & "," & _
        ServerTime)
End If
Next


For Each objItem1 in colLoggedEvents2
If objItem1.EventType=1 then
    objFile.WriteLine("Logfile: " & objItem1.Logfile & "," & " source " & objItem1.SourceName & "," & _
        "Message: " & objItem1.Message & "," & _
        "TimeGenerated: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem1.TimeGenerated) & "," & _
        ServerTime)
End If
Next                                                               


For Each objItem2 in colLoggedEvents3        
If objItem2.EventType=1 then
    objFile.WriteLine("Logfile: " & objItem2.Logfile & "," & " source " & objItem2.SourceName & "," & _
        "Message: " & objItem2.Message & "," & _
        "TimeGenerated: " & WMIDateStringToDate(objItem2.TimeGenerated) & "," & _
        ServerTime)
End If
Next

Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmDate) 
 WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _ 
 Mid(dtmDate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmDate, 4) _ 
 & " " & Mid (dtmDate, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmDate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmDate,13, 2)) 
End Function

objFile.Close
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: I would try this and let you know, thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Your script threw error at lines 44, 54 and 64. The reson was there was '&' missing. I added '&' this but after that nothing happens at running the script, even it does not throw any error.

Comment: @IftakharAhmad I've just edited the answer and corrected what you said. Does it create the CSV file?

Comment: It is taking the same amount of time even when writing to CSV.

Comment: We have migrated to Windows Server 2012 and there the same script is working OK. It writes the event logs in excel in few seconds.